# BigQuery triggers for a data notification server

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, autobahn

I am writing a notification server to provide real time updates to ui. This is done using [autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) with python to achieve something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIdmk2doU8w&feature=youtu.be). So my data resides in Bigquery. I want to send notifications to ui as soon as data updates in my table. Since there is no SQL triggers for bigquery I thought of having this scenario for that.

1. Create a task scheduling provided in [Appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron).
2. Use a [table decorator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators)  inside the job to execute every second.

eg: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [digin_duosoftware_com.test123@-1-]`

Or even a simple query to respond with data every second.

My question is it acceptable to have this implementation for such scenario since I run it every second? or is there any other way to achieve this?

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498876/how-can-i-trigger-an-email-or-other-notification-based-on-a-bigquery-query) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per table decoration use:
relative value for time in decorator must be in milliseconds

```
eg: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [digin_duosoftware_com.test123@-1000-]
```

> I want to send notifications to ui as soon as data updates in my table

Instead of polling from data itself - you can rather use [tables.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get) API to check [lastModifiedTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#lastModifiedTime) table's property and then act based on it

Comment: So using a decorator inside a job I have to keep polling the lastmodifieddate? or directly from python call the api every second to check whether its updated?

Comment: i would call tables.get from your code every second and if `lastModifiedTime` is changed - do whatever logic you have to update UI

Comment: ok thanks for clear explanation. +1 I will accept this after implementing it. :)