# Setup a BigQuery alert when a certain attribute passes a certain value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to get an alert to my email when a certain attribute in BigQuery is outside a range of values. Is there a way I could do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'attribute'? Can you provide an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Do you talk about the data inside BigQuery? Or the metadata, like the table size, number of rows, number of billed byte by query,...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The attribute I'm talking about is an attribute from one of my relations (data inside the BigQuery). I would like to calculate its mean, and if one day (my DB updates daily) its value would be really higher than the mean or really lower, I would like to be notified.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible to do directly with Stackdriver Alerts and BigQuery, because [BigQuery Stackdriver Alerts is based on certain conditions of metrics of Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#create-alert) and the result of a query isn't.
However, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26499697/12821865), you can use something like AppEngine to achieve send email notifications based on the result of a query.